# Inconsistent Solr Search Behavior for Customers with Job and Customers Without Job - Partial vs. Whole Word Search Issue

Tags: solr, laravel-4, solarium

We are facing a puzzling issue with Solr search integration in Laravel, and we could really use some expert guidance to resolve this matter.

Our project involves indexing data on Solr using Laravel. Within our indexed data, we have two distinct types of customers - Customers with Job and Customers Without Job.

However, we have noticed a perplexing difference in the search behavior of Solr for these two customer types:

**For Customers with Job:**

As we start typing a word in the search input, Solr immediately returns relevant data (partial word search).

**For Customers Without Job:**

Solr only returns data after we have entered the entire word (full word search).

This inconsistent behavior is creating confusion for our users and negatively impacting the user experience. Ideally, we want Solr to exhibit the same partial word search behavior for both customer types.

Upon inspecting our indexing configuration in Laravel, we haven't identified any noticeable discrepancies between the data of Customers with Job and Customers Without Job.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Solr integration in Laravel, or is there a specific configuration or setting that might be causing this difference in search behavior between the two customer types?

We would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or potential solutions to ensure uniform search behavior for both types of customers using Solr in Laravel.

Thank you so much for your assistance!

**For Customers Without Job:**

Solr should return data as soon as we start typing a word.

**Note:**

We are using Dismax query parser and searching on multiple fields.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share the fields searched for and the field type defination of it

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Fields on which we are searching: full_name, secondary_name, first_name, last_name, full_name_reverse, customer_contact_first_name, customer_city, customer_state,  zip and field type definition is text_general like this.

`<field name="first_name" type="text_general" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

Comment: could you share data samples with like one having job and one does not? did you also using auto suggest?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Here are data samples: Without Job:
`{"doc_id":[X],"customer_id":[X],"first_name":["X"],"last_name":["X"],"phones":["XXXX"],"phone_number":[0],"customer_custom_fields":["{\"data\":[]}"],"id":"X-X-X-X","_version_":X}` 
With Job:`{"doc_id":[X],"customer_id":[X],"first_name":["X"],"last_name":["X"],"job_id":[X],"job_addres":["X"],"job_city":["XXX"],"job_zip":[XXX],"job_state":["X"],"job_country":["X"],"phones":["X"],"phone_number":[X],"multi_job":[0],"parent_id":[0],,"with_job":[true],"customer_custom_fields":[],"job_custom_fields":[""],"id":"X-X-X-X","_version_":X}`

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti And yes we are using auto auggest